# Have an div the same size as its parent (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a few div's called item. They are used with flex-boxes.
Inside those items I wan't a div with the exact same dimensions.
But for some reason they get the same size as the container.

How can I have `.background-img` have the same size as `.item`?

The transition when clicking should still work as it does now.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="background: red"><div class="background-img"></div></div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green"><div class="background-img"></div></div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue"><div class="background-img"></div></div>
    <div class="item" style="background: purple"><div class="background-img"></div></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".item").click(function() {

    var focused = $(this).hasClass("focused");    

    if (!focused) {

        $(".item").not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("collapse");    
        });

        $(this).addClass("focused");

    }
    else {
        $(".item").removeClass("collapse");    
        $(this).removeClass("focused");
    }

});
```

css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.collapse {
    height: 0%;
}

.focused {

}

.background-img {
    /* not this */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/L8hktsgn/15/

Answer (score 0):

Add a *position relative* to your `.item`

```
.item {
  position: relative;
}
```

then *position absolute* to `.background-img` with all *side to 0*

```
.background-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

It will follow his parent now.